# How to kill tasks which begin with string using python

Tags: python, startswith, taskkill

I use the following commands to kill a task in Task Manager.

```
os.system("taskkill /f /im  " + ProgName)
```

It works fine for most tasks but I found one that it fails to kill.

```
CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe
```

I think its because it has more than one period in the name but I am not sure.
I tried multiple variations of the name.

```
CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe
CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess
\"CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe\"
\"CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess\"
```

Is there a way to kill all tasks that begin with a string (e.x. CefSharp*) using python3?

P.S. this is my very first question on the site, please forgive my ignorance of the subject and any mistakes in tagging or phrasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows `taskkill` tool does take wildcards, so it should be possible to test:

```
os.system("taskkill /F /IM CefSharp* /T")
```

`/T` is used to kill all child processes.

Or as follows:

```
ProgName = "CefSharp*"
os.system(f"taskkill /F /IM {ProgName} /T")
```